# Running WAMP & IIS Together On The Same Server

Tags: php, .net, wordpress, iis, wamp

First question on here!

I've been searching through like crazy trying to figure out a solution to my company's web issues.

Okay, my company has been using IIS to host their own website and client websites. They write all of their applications in .NET.

They wanted a much more robust personal website and agreed that they wanted to go with Wordpress for their new personal site.

But they want to be able to serve both sets of content from one server and one domain name.

I have successfully installed WAMP and have it running concurrently with IIS. WAMP is currently running on Port 81.

Now here's my question:

Is there any way to have it where when people visit the main domain - that they see the WAMP server - and then when they direct themselves to other content - that they see the IIS server?

Is this possible some-way?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can't you just install wordpress on IIS server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This contains the basic idea behind how you would set something like that up:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/

Obviously skip the bit about creating the website as you already have them. Rather than pointing it to another IIS site on a port just point the appropriate rules to the port your apache is running on (81)

Although you can run PHP on IIS and not have to mess around with this.